# How do I perform specific parentless requests using Restangular in a neat way?

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

Say I have an API endpoint at `/users` and another one at `/cars`. Naturally, a `GET` request to either of them will get all users or cars available. Now, a `GET /users/74/cars` should return all cars belonging to user 74.

But my app has many models related to cars, not just users, so more endpoints exist like `/shops/34/cars` and `/mechanics/12/cars`. For simplicity, I want all `PUT/PATCH` requests to be made to the main `/cars` endpoint.

At the moment of performing the save, Restangular will by default do a `PUT` request to the endpoint through which the item was loaded. But that endpoint do not exist.

It also provides a nice `Restangular.setParentless(['cars'])` method that will discard the first part of the url. However, I don't want to do this globally, but specifically for a particular element.

The neatest would actually do it globally, but restrict it for a specific method, like: `Restangular.setParentless(['cars'], ['PUT'])`.

Anything like that around? Or am I overcomplicating it?

So far I tried stuff I don't like:

```
delete car.parentResource;
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Haven't changed it. I clone the element, delete `parentResource` and perform the operation. Ugly.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [using self reference links](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-self-reference-resources). A self reference link is a link which stores the route which should be used for `GET`/`PUT`/`DELETE` etc. on the item, rather than the URL from which it was pulled.

Example, update the mileage on one of user id 74's cars:

First, configure Restangular to look for a self link  property called 'self' on each object.

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  selfLink: 'self'
});
```

Next, make your call to get the cars. I'll assume that you have already modified your API to return a property called 'self' on each object that has the URL to it's proper API endpoint.

```
GET /users/74/cars

[
  {
    "id": 12,
    "model": "Camaro",
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "year": 1969,
    "color": "red",
    "odometer": 67294,
    "license": "ABC12345",
    "self": "/cars/12"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "model": "Gallardo",
    "make": "Lamborghini",
    "year": 2015,
    "color": "black",
    "odometer": 521,
    "license": "XYZ34567",
    "self": "/cars/14"
  }
]
```

We want to add some miles to one of them, and then save it. The entire Restangular code would look like:

```
Restangular.one('users', 74).all('cars').getList().then(function(cars){
    cars[1].odometer = 613;
    cars[1].put();
});
```

The `PUT` will go to `/cars/14` instead of `/users/74/cars/14`. This is very useful for applications like yours that relate models as a graph rather than a strict hierarchical tree.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. However, I don't like the fact of having to change my API for this. I have this problem with three projects, and on one of them I can't change the API. I'm guessing your answer is 2/3rds right.